# Proving a graph is planar - mutually tangent circles in a plane

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, planar-graphs

> Let $C_1,\dots ,C_n$ be circles in the plane with pairwise disjoint
>   interiors. Define the tangency graph to have $n$ vertices such
>   that vertices are adjacent if the corresponding circles are tangent to
>   each other. Prove this graph is planar.

It looks like I have to prove there can't be minor $K_5$'s or $K_{3,3}$'s. For $K_5$, I thought to prove there's no $K_4$ anywhere. Thing is, I don't even know how to rigorously prove we can't have four pairwise tangent circles in the plane. This doesn't even cover minors and I have no idea how to tackle $K_{3,3}$'s... How to solve this problem? How should such problems be approached?

Comment: There *are* four pairwise tangent circles in the plane - take any three pairwise tangent circles and fit a fourth one in the middle.

Can you construct an explicit embedding in the plane, with vertices at the circle centers?

Comment: @arkeet sorry, I don't follow - an embedding of what? And how do I explain why there are four tangent circles without delving into every geometric detail?

Comment: If you want to talk about four tangent circles, it is just a special case of [Appolonius problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius#Mutually_tangent_given_circles:_Soddy.27s_circles_and_Descartes.27_theorem). But it's not really related to the solution. What @arkeet says is that, if you consider the vertices to be the circles' centers, and the edges as defined in your problem, you can prove that this graph is planar.

Comment: @Mariuslp how? $\;$

Comment: The main idea by the way of contradiction: assume the graph is not planar, therefore two edges crosses each other. Then (it's the boring part) you prove that this implies that the four circles involved with these edges overlap in a way or an other. I don't have time to write a full answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mariuslp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/363021/) said in the comments, you can explicitly construct a planar embedding of the tangency graph. Given your collection of circles $C_1, \dotsc, C_n$ that are pairwise disjoint in the plane, construct the graph by taking a vertex at the center of each circle and connecting vertices by an edge if the two circles are tangent. Note that each edge will pass through the point of tangency and that each edge is completely contained in the interior of the two tangent circles. I claim that this graph is planar.

For the sake of finding a contradiction, if this graph weren't planar then there would be a pair of intersecting edges $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ which are between the vertices $a,b$ and $c,d$ respectively, which are at the centers of the circles $C_a$, $C_b$, $C_c$, and $C_d$ respectively. Without loss of generality, let $t$ be the point of tangency of $C_a$ and $C_b$ and suppose that $t$ does not lie on $(c,d)$. Then $t$ must lie on one side $(c,d)$<sup>[1]</sup>, so one of the circles $C_c$ or $C_d$ intersects $(c,d)$, contradicting that the interior the circles are disjoint. The other case is that the points of tangency of the two pairs of circles are the same point and lie at the intersection of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. But in this specific case we can clearly see that some of the must circles intersect. This contradicts the possibility of the graph being non-planar.

---

[1] To be more precise $t$ must lie on one side of the line containing $(c,d)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious: Take the centers $v_i$ $(1\leq i\leq n)$ of the circles as vertices and connect two vertices by a straight segment if the corresponding circles are tangent to each other.

Or have I missed something?

Comment: That's the natural construction, yes. But there's something to proving that the resulting graph is planar.

Comment: To complement Mike's answer, the claim is not true for arbitrary non-degenerate convex polygons that have disjoint interiors, and represent each an edge if they touch (i.e., boundaries share a point).